# AngularJS and WordPress API display data from single post

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wordpress, api

I'm using the WordPress API as a data service to an AngularJS/Ionic app. I have a post type called programmes and have a list of programmes (posts) and the JSON looks like:

```
var programmes = [
 {
  id: 6,
  title: "A post",
  slug: "a-post"
 },
 {
  id: 7,
  title: "Another post",
  slug: "another-post"
 },
 {
  id: 8,
  title: "Post 123",
  slug: "post-123"
 }
]
```

I've got the list of programmes displaying with ngRepeat. However I'm struggling to get the data for an individual post.

I was trying to do it like so to get data for the single programme: `var programme = programmes[$stateParams.programmeId];` however the issue is, for example, if I click on the first "A post" it returns `6` from the programme id but this does not match the index of the object which is `0`.

How can I get data from a single programme when the id and index do not match without having to manually reset the programme id's in the database?

Here are my files so far:

**app.js**

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

  .state('app', {
    url: "/app",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
    controller: 'AppCtrl'
  })

  .state('app.programmes', {
    url: "/programmes",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/programmes.html",
        controller: 'ProgrammesCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('app.programme', {
    url: "/programmes/:programmeSlug",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/programme.html",
        controller: 'ProgrammeCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/programmes');
});
```

**data.js**

```
.factory('DataFactory', function($http) {

  var urlBase = 'http://event-app.dev/wp-json/wp/v2';
  var APIdata = {};

  var currentProgramme = null;

  return {
    getProgrammes: function() {
      return $http.get(urlBase + '/programmes');
    }
  }
})
```

**controllers.js**

```
.controller ('ProgrammesCtrl', function ($scope, DataFactory) {
  getProgrammes();
  function getProgrammes() {
    DataFactory.getProgrammes().then(function(response) {  
      $scope.programmes = response.data;
    }, 
    function(error) {
      $scope.status = 'Unable to load data';
    });
  }
})

.controller ('ProgrammeCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams, DataFactory) {
  getProgrammes();
  function getProgrammes() {
    DataFactory.getProgrammes().then(function(response, id) { 
      var programmes = response.data;
      $scope.programme = programmes[$stateParams.programmeId];

    }, 
    function(error) {
      $scope.status = 'Unable to load data';
    });
  }
})
```

**programme.html (view to display a single programme)**

```
<ion-view view-title="{{programme.title}}">
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item>
        {{programme.title}}
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use simple loop on *programmes* array to find specific single *programme*. See the modified `getProgrammes()` function below:

```
 function getProgrammes() {
            DataFactory.getProgrammes().then(function (response, id) {
                    var programmes = response.data;
                    for (var i = 0; i < programmes.length; i++) {
                        if (programmes[i].id == $stateParams.programmeId) {
                            $scope.programme = programmes[i];
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                },
                function (error) {
                    $scope.status = 'Unable to load data';
                });
        }
```